# How Do Gradle Script Without Tasks Work?

Tags: gradle

I had a dependency issue (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException)  with this gradle script https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy/blob/master/ant2ivy.groovy

When I looked closer it was using Grapes instead of a dependencies block and there was a "Main Program" that calls a class defined in the script instead of using tasks.

It is an application rather than a build script really.

This isn't what I have been used to with gradle so far. Is there documentation around this style of use?

It isn't the same as the Application plugin http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a gradle script - it is just a groovy script.

Comment: Yeah. I realised that when I woke up this morning. Time to go to bed earlier!